# How to Remove AdMob Using In-App Purchase

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase

I know this is a duplicate of many other questions, but I have never got a good answer. Does anyone know a good tutorial how to remove AdMob with an In-App Purchase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do:

1- Create a non-consumable product in your in app purchase list of products.

2- Implemente the logic to allow the user to buy that product.

3- Once the product is bought, set a global variable in your NSUserDefaults:

```
[[NSUSerDefauls standarUSerDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isAdMobDisabled"]
```

4- Before adding the add, check if that variable is YES/NO:

```
if (![[NSUSerDefauls standarUSerDefaults] boolForKey:@"isAdMobDisabled"])
{
    self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
    self.bannerView.adUnitID = adMobID;
    self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
    [self.bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
```

Let me know if you need more help with any of the steps

Comment: I have did everything in iTunes Connect, so I will remove my code for AdMob in viewDidLoad and check NSUserDefaults if isAdMobDisabled is YES or NO (so it's NO as standard). If it's YES, I will have nothing, but if it's NO, I will load an AdMob ad?

Comment: Yes, default value is NO, so load the banner if YES